# Write PHP Script to select special generated thumbnails Info on Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

this is actually a very complicated question so i'll start to explain it.

1. I have a CMS called 'FusionCMS' which uses Codeigniter.
2. It Dynamically Generate the pages ( like news ) so they looks like domain.com/news/1 or /2 etc.. but that folders actually doesn't really exist.
3. There is header.tpl file in view file which contains the meta tags.
4. I make a PHP script to select special text from database to be as og tags.
5. what i means with oh tags are the facebook meta tags exp : og:title - og:description.
6. I want them to be selected depends on the page link ( exp if it's /news/11 ) than to select the ID 11 from database which will have title and content which will be what i need.

This are the codes ( PHP is missing the selection from URL and some modifications ).
The TPL file is very big so i'll just put some of it.

PHP

```
if(isset($_GET['post'])) {
    $postid = $_GET['post'];
    $conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","ascent","fusioncms");
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT title, description FROM news WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $postid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($title, $message);
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        while($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo "<meta name='og:title' content='".$title."'>";
            echo "<meta name='og:description' content='".$message."'>";
        }
    }
}else{
    echo "<meta name='og:title' content='Example Page for JadaDev'>";
    echo "<meta name='og:description' content='Some random description'>";
}
```

This is the TPL file ( header.tpl )

```
 <!-- Custom Scripts -->
    <meta property="og:title" content="{$title}"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="{$path}"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://127.0.0.1/application/themes/default/images/tam.png"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="حزب تيار المحبة"/>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="2217370698541973" />
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="John.Evenetcha"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="{$title}"/>
    <!-- End of Custom -->
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: The issue here that i want to put the PHP code in the tpl file putting as regular ?php will be shown in the page and won't work and using {php} {/php} didn't really work it gives a huge errors so i wonder how this will work

Comment: Try creating a [mcve] to replicate the problem.

Comment: I read that before, if you did notice it's an already made CMS that have more than 3.000 files and pretty complicated to get what i want and i need much knowledge so best thing is to add the PHP in the tpl file or else add regular php file and add connection between each other that i don't know how to do so..

Comment: its impossible to provide you a solution with the information you have given. make your question more MCVE